# Why is LH repeated in equation 35 of the yellow paper?

Tags: blocks, yellow-paper, block-header

Excerpt from page 5 of the yellow paper, version `e94ebda`:

[image: Serialisation functions]

I understand that `LX` is the preparation function for serialising `X`, as follows:

- `LB` for blocks
- `LH` for block headers
- `LU` for ommer block headers

And `B` represents the block tuple `(BH, BT, BU)`:

- `BH` represents the headers
- `BT` [_] the transactions
- `BU` [_] the ommer block headers

In the image above, shouldn't the second `LH` actually be `LU`, that is, the preparation function for the ommer block headers?

Is it because there's no need for a new preparation function because `LH` already has sufficient properties to compute the ommer block headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same function, it has an asterisk and, as per the definition right after the excerpt in the posted image, a function `L(x)*` is an element-wise sequence transformation:

[image]